# 8-bit Bitwise for 64 bit integer

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, avr

I want to implement bitwise cyclic shift of a 64 bit integer.

`ROT(a,b)` will  move bit at position `i` to position `i+b`. (a is the 64 bit integer)

However, my avr processor is an 8-bit processor. Thus, to express `a`, I have to use 
`unit8_t x[8]`.

- `x[0]` is the 8 most significant bits of `a`.
- `x[7]` is the 8 least significant bits of `a`.

Can any one help to implement `ROT(a,b)` in term of array `x`?

Thank you

Comment: Is there anything that you tried?

Comment: Is there a specific programming language you want an answer in? Also x[0] has the **8** most significant bits of a, right?

Comment: Basically, you can either do this in pieces, or you can see if the compiler will do it for you.  Just for laughs I asked avr-gcc to do some operations on a `uint64_t` and it did not *complain* - though I'll caution that *I haven't actually tested the result*.  (I guess you would still have to synthesize rotation from shifts.)

Comment: Thank you all, I want to do it in C. Actually, it is a part of exercise which requires me to transform the code :D. I did give it a try but the result is not correct.

Comment: What is `i` in "ROT(a,b) will move bit at position i to position i+b. (a is the 64 bit integer)"?  Don't your need `ROT(a,i,b)`?

Comment: actually, 0<i<63, it will move all bit to the left b times.

Answer (score 3):

It makes no *functional* difference if the underlying processor is 64-bit, 8-bit or 1-bit.  If the compiler is compliant - you are good to go.   Use `uint64_t`.  Code does not "have to use `unit8_t`" because the processor is an 8-bit one.

```
uint64_t RPT(uint64_t a, unsigned b) {
  return (a << (b & 63))  |  (a >> ((64 - b) & 63));
}
```

Extra () added for explicitness.
`& 63` (or `%64` is you like that style)  added to insure only 6 LSBits of `b` contribute to the shift.  Any higher bits simply imply multiple "revolutions" of a circular shift.
`((64 - b) & 63)` could be simplified to `(-b & 63)`.

--

But if OP still wants "implement `ROT(a,b)` in term of array `unit8_t x[8]`":

```
#include <stdint.h>

// circular left shift.  MSByte in a[0].
void ROT(uint8_t *a, unsigned b) {
  uint8_t dest[8];
  b &= 63;

  // byte shift
  unsigned byte_shift = b / 8;
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    dest[i] = a[(i + byte_shift) & 7];
  }

  b &= 7; // b %= 8;  form bit shift;
  unsigned acc = dest[0] << b;
  for (unsigned i = 8; i-- > 0;) {
    acc >>= 8;
    acc |= (unsigned) dest[i] << b;
    a[i] = (uint8_t) acc;
  }
}
```

---

@vlad_tepesch Suggested a solution that emphasizes the AVR 8-bit nature.  This is an untested attempt.

```
void ROT(uint8_t *a, uint8_t b) {
  uint8_t dest[8];
  b &= 63;  // Could be eliminated as following code only uses the 6 LSBits.

  // byte shift
  uint8_t byte_shift = b / 8u;
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 8u; i++) {
    dest[i] = a[(i + byte_shift) & 7u];
  }

  b &= 7u; // b %= 8u;  form bit shift;
  uint16_t acc = dest[0] << b;
  for (unsigned i = 8u; i-- > 0;) {
    acc >>= 8u;
    acc |= (uint8_t) dest[i] << b;
    a[i] = (uint8_t) acc;
  }
}
```

Comment: your RPT functions second arguement should be uint8_t to save the efford to fill an additional 8bit register thats not required. i think the `& 63` is unneccesssary overhead. the `((64 - b) & 63))` part would be better as `(64 - (b&63))`. 1. it would be more intuitive 2. the compiler may better see that he can reuse the `b&63` expression 3. it may be more save if b is larger than 64 (iam not sure about this if it really is a difference - iam to tired to think about)

Comment: @vlad_tepesch OP hasn't defined the type of 2nd argument. Though not a bad idea, the preferred integer size is `int/unsigned` unless there is compelling reason otherwise. Given opcode and bus-alignment issues, filling `uint8_t` can easily be more code/time than filling `unsigned`. The `&63` is there to prevent “undefined behavior” (UB).  Any shift, left or right, of a `uint64_t` by a value outside the range 0-63 is UB.  A typical compiler will only use the lower 6 LSBits anyways and optimize this `& 63` away. `(64 - (b&63))` can lead to the result of 64 when `b` is 0.  This again leads to UB.

Comment: the compelling reason to use 8bit is that we are talking about 8bit processors with 8bit buswidth, 8bit register width and 8bit arithmetic operations. p̶l̶e̶a̶s̶e̶ ̶s̶h̶o̶w̶ ̶m̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶p̶a̶r̶a̶g̶r̶a̶p̶h̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶s̶t̶a̶t̶e̶s̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶s̶h̶i̶f̶t̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶0̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶U̶B̶.̶ ok i understood your intention about this

Comment: @vlad_tepesch Right you are about 8-bit AVR.  Changing `unsigned b` to `uint_8 b` certainly can be done.  I'm am not familiar enough with the compiler to know the optimization effects on `dest[i] = a[(i + byte_shift) & 7u];` with `uint8_t i, byte_shift` etc. Suggest insuring unsigned math with explicit unsigned constants like `8u, 7u`.

Answer (score 1):

why do not leave the work to the compiler and just implement a function

```
uint64_t rotL(uint64_t v, uint8_t r){
  return  (v>>(64-r)) | (v<<r)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I take it the x(i) are 8 bits.
To rotate left n times
each bit from X(i,j) where i is the index array x(0) -> x(7)
                     and   j is the bit position within the element

then this bit will end up in 
Y((i+n)/8, ( i+n) & 7 )
This will handle rotations up to 63
any number > 63 , you just mod it.

Comment: Correction  Y((i+n)/8, ( i+n) & 7 )  should be  Y((i+n)/8, ( j+n) & 7 )

Comment: Hi, i do not really understand your answer, can you elaborate? What is your Y(a,b)?. Thank you

Comment: if I understand correctly, your Y(a,b) is the new position for each bit come from X(i,j)? However, if n=4, then X(0,0) becomes Y(0,4) which is not correct or X(2,0) becomes Y(0,4) ? Please help me correct if i wrong

Comment: well you're starting with an array of 8 8bits values X and the result will be in a new array Y of 8 8 bits. zero out the Y array first and then loop through each X ( in my example X(0) is the least significant byte ) and for each X loop through each bit.

Comment: void Rotate ( unsigned char *x, unsigned char *y, int n )
{
unsigned char[8] = { 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128 };
n &= 63;
for ( int i = 0; i < 7; i++ )
  y(i) = 0;
for ( int i = 0; i < 7; i++ )
  {
  for int ( j= 0; j < 7; j++ )
    {
    if ( x(i) & bit(j) )
      {
      y[(i+n)/8] |= bit[(j+n) & 7];
      }    
    }
}